# Hibernate createCriteria JOIN, ORDER, DISTINCT from one level

Tags: hibernate, grails, createcriteria

I have 3 classes: first, second, third
I have createria approximately like this:

```
First.createCriteria().listDistinct {
            if(....){fetchMode("second", FetchMode.JOIN)
            fetchMode("second.third", FetchMode.JOIN)}
            order(sortOrder, orderBy)
            order("id", "desc")
}
```

(when "if" false, createCriteria works fine)

when "if" true Hibernate generated sql request like this

```
select 
  distinct id,
  secondfield
from
  FIRST as firsts
inner join
  SECOND
       ... on ...
inner join
  THIRD
       ... on ...
where(...)
order by 
     firsts.name asc
     firsts.id desc
```

But so sql request cannot be executed because (distinct, join, order by) cannot be on the same level togehter.
I lunch it in SQL developer. This request without one of (distinct, join, order by) works fine.
What can I do with this.
May by I can coerce hibernate do (join, distinct) and (order) in "different SELECT" levels?
How i can wrap SELECT by another SELECT?

```
select *
from 
   (select 
     distinct id,
     secondfield
   from
     FIRST as firsts
   inner join
     SECOND
          ... on ...
   where(......))
order by
    (......)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Groovy.SQL.* which gives you a lot moore flexibility than HQL queries.

Try this:  http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL